# Clearing vs restoring an object in Java

Tags: java

This is the question I am being asked.

Implement the following two static methods. Note that, although the two methods compute the same function, the first one clears the given NaturalNumber while the second one restores it.
(naturalnumber is a class that makes a special kind of number)

I am not looking for the answer, just a clarification of what they mean by clear vs restore. I have posted a link to the complete assignment below.

[Assignment](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/software/2221/web-sw1/assignments/homeworks/review3.html)

Comment: Hmm, it seems  a bit ambiguous - I agree w/ Ted Hop though. But if possibl, ask the prof

Comment: You might ask on Math.SE though, this seems like a math thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't standard terminology; it probably has something to do with the implementation of `NaturalNumber`. As a guess, I'd say that the method that *clears* `n` will return with `n` set to all zeroes, while the one that *restores* `n` will return with `n` unchanged (or perhaps changed while the method executes but then put back the way it was before it returns).

Just to be sure, ask your TA for clarification.

Comment: Thanks, if the TA or profesor returned emails then I would ask them. But I see what you are saying. Thanks..